# How do I create a function that will delete checkboxes "tasks" that i added upon checking them?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, task

I am doing an assignment and I'm creating a task manager. I've got the adding a new task working, however I am having trouble reversing that once you click on a checkbox the opposite happens. I'm pretty sure it almost works, there's probably just a couple lines that need tweaking.

Here is all my HTML and JS/jQuery code for context:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>

        <div id="sidebar">
            <h2>Overall Status</h2>

                <div class="sb" id="schl.stat">
                    <h3>School -</h3>
                        <input type="submit" id="schl.bttn" value="0">
                </div>

                <div class="sb">
                    <h3>Work -</h3>
                        <input type="submit" id="wrk.bttn" value="0">
                </div>

                <div class="sb">
                    <h3>Weekend -</h3>
                        <input type="submit" id="wknd.bttn" value="0">
                </div>

                <div class="sb">
                    <h3>Other -</h3>
                        <input type="submit" id="othr.bttn" value="0">
                </div>

         </div>

         <div id="tasks">
             <div id="newtask">
                 <h2>Add New Task</h2>


                 <div id="IDK">
                     <div id="idk">
                        <label for="options">Options*</label>
                            <select id="options">
                                <option hidden disabled selected value>------------------------------------------</option>
                                <option value="School">School</option>
                                <option value="Work">Work</option>
                                <option value="Weekend">Weekend</option>
                                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                            </select>
                     </div>

                        <div id="idk2">
                            <label for="date">Completion Date</label>
                                <input type="date" id="date">
                        </div>
                 </div>

                    <label for="tdesc">Description*</label>
                        <input type="text" id="tdesc" size="75">

                    <input type="submit" id="add" value="Add">
                        <div id="req"><strong>* Required fields</strong></div> 
            </div>




              <div id="current">

                    <h2>Current Tasks</h2>

                          <div id="schlwrk">
                              <div id="schl">
                                  <h4>School</h4>
                                  <br>
                              </div>

                              <div id="wrk">
                                  <h4>Work</h4>
                                  <br>
                              </div>
                          </div>

                          <div id="wkndothr">
                                <div id="wknd">
                                  <h4>Weekend</h4>
                                  <br>
                                </div>
                                <div id="othr">
                                  <h4>Other</h4>
                                  <br>
                                </div>
                          </div>
              </div>



        </div>
</div>
```

**JS/jQuery:**

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;
var d = 0;



function addTask() {

  var newTask = $("#tdesc").val();
  var newTask2 = $("#date").val();

  if ($("#options").val() == "" || $("#tdesc").val() == "") {
    alert("You have not completed all required fields.");

  } else if ($("#options").val() == "School") {
    $("#schl").append("<input type='checkbox'" + 
                     "name='checkbox'" + 
                     "class='checkbox1'" +
                     "value=" + 
                     newTask +
                     newTask2 +
                     "'>" +
                     newTask +
                     newTask2 +
                     "<br>");

  document.getElementById("schl.bttn").value = ++a;

  } else if ($("#options").val() == "Work") {
    $("#wrk").append("<input type='checkbox'" + 
                     "name='checkbox'" + 
                     "class='checkbox2'" +
                     "value=" + 
                     newTask +
                     newTask2 +
                     "'>" +
                     newTask +
                     newTask2 +
                    "<br>");

    document.getElementById("wrk.bttn").value = ++b;

  } else if ($("#options").val() == "Weekend") {
    $("#wknd").append("<input type='checkbox'" + 
                     "name='checkbox'" + 
                     "class='checkbox3'" +
                     "value=" + 
                     newTask +
                     newTask2 +
                     "'>" +
                     newTask +
                     newTask2 +
                     "<br>");

    document.getElementById("wknd.bttn").value = ++c;

  } else {
    $("#othr").append("<input type='checkbox'" + 
                     "name='checkbox'" + 
                     "class='checkbox4'" +
                     "value=" + 
                     newTask +
                     newTask2 +
                     "'>" +
                     newTask +
                     newTask2 +
                     "<br>");

    document.getElementById("othr.bttn").value = ++d;
  }

  $("#tdesc").val("");
  $("#date").val("");

}

$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#add").on("click", function() {
         addTask();
});
});












**var checkBox1 = $(".checkbox1");
var checkBox2 = $(".checkbox2");
var checkBox3 = $(".checkbox3");
var checkBox4 = $(".checkbox4");
function deleteTask() {

if (checkBox1.is(":checked")) {
    $("schl").remove("<input type='checkbox'" + 
                     "name='checkbox'" + 
                     "class='checkbox1'" +
                     "value=" + 
                     newTask + 
                     newTask2 +
                     "'>" +
                     newTask +
                     newTask2 +
                     "<br>");

document.getElementById("schl.bttn").value = --a;

} else if (checkBox2.is(":checked")) {
    $("wrk").remove("<input type='checkbox'" + 
                     "name='checkbox'" + 
                     "class='checkbox2'" +
                     "value=" + 
                     newTask +
                     newTask2 +
                     "'>" +
                     newTask +
                     newTask2 +
                    "<br>");

document.getElementById("wrk.bttn").value = --b;

} else if (checkBox3.is(":checked")) {
    $("wknd").remove("<input type='checkbox'" + 
                     "name='checkbox'" + 
                     "class='checkbox3'" +
                     "value=" + 
                     newTask +
                     newTask2 +
                     "'>" +
                     newTask +
                     newTask2 +
                     "<br>");

document.getElementById("wknd.bttn").value = --c;

} else {
    $("othr").remove("<input type='checkbox'" + 
                     "name='checkbox'" + 
                     "class='checkbox4'" +
                     "value=" + 
                     newTask +
                     newTask2 +
                     "'>" +
                     newTask +
                     newTask2 +
                     "<br>");

document.getElementById("othr.bttn").value = --d;
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(":checkbox").on("click", function() {
         deleteTask();
});
});**
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the event handler "on click" is set when the document is ready, and at that point there is no checkbox on the document (thus, deleteTask is never called).

You should set the on click event handler in addCheckbox.

However, there are other problems in your code:

- You have multiple `$(document).ready(function(){});`, use only one in your code.
- You should create your checkboxes this way, your code will be more readable:

```
$('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', value: newTask+newTask2, class: 'checkbox4' }).appendTo($('#othr'));
$('<label />', {  text: newTask+newTask2 }).appendTo($('#othr'));
```

- You should use a unique id (by adding the `id` attribute) on your checkboxes, and reference this id in the [`for` attribute of your labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label), so the user can click on the label to check the box.
- On your `on click` handler, you can use `$(this)` to get the item clicked by the user (for example, when you want to find the checkbox the user has clicked on).

Comment: Do I still need to add an id since there'll be multiple checkboxes within each section and I don't want people to be able to click on the text and make it check the box? Also I'm not sure on how to add the event handler, I added this into each section: onclick: 'deleteTask(this)',